# Set difference bijection proof (stuck on injective)

Tags: proof-writing

So here is the question I'm working on

So obviously I need to prove two things, that its both injective and surjective, however I'm trying to show it is injective and am currently stuck, here is what I have

As you can see, double containment to show an arbitrary x is in both little a and little b is possible, but I have no clue how to do that.

Any ideas?

Thanks!

Comment: what's "WTS" stand for?

Comment: Want To Show, sorry about that

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just prove that the function is an involution, that is $f\circ f = Id_{\wp(X)}$. It will follow that it's injective (otherwise it would not be invertible) and surjective (otherwise it wouldn't be the inverse of another function).

Comment: Oh brainwave! Thanks a ton. Good "trick" here to prove involution + surjective instead of injective surjective.